# How can I change the behavior of Android's airplane mode so that it will not turn off the cellular radio?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, action

I have been trying to create a simple application that will let the user customize the behavior of airplane mode in Android.  The motivation for this is from a relative who has a Samsung Fascinate, and during calls he will accidentally turn on airplane mode.  This happens when he holds the phone, accidentally holds down the side power/lock button, which opens a dialog with a menu for “Silent Mode”, “Airplane Mode”, and “Power Off”.  He  accidentally triggers airplane mode by a touch of the phone to his cheek.  This drops the call and is an annoyance to him.

Ultimately, I would like to create an app that prevents the cellular radio from being turned off while the user is in the middle of a call.  But, for a first iteration I thought it made sense to let the user manually choose which radios would **not** get turned off by airplane mode.

I am **not** looking to modify the Android source code or do something that would require rooting. I am looking for a solution within the standard framework

My first attempt to solve this was to create an application that would modify `System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS` like so:

```
System.putString(getApplication().getContentResolver(), System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS, "");
```

[According to the API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS), this constant is "A comma separated list of radios that need to be disabled when airplane mode is on".  It seems that airplane mode does not actually use this constant, and it continues to work as normal after the change is made.

My next attempt was to create a BroadCastReceiver, receive the AIRPLANE_MODE action, and send out an Intent to reverse it:

```
Intent am = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", 0);
context.sendBroadcast(am);
```

This does turn off airplane mode after it has been activated.  However, if the user was in the middle of a call, it will still be dropped (which makes sense).  So, this is not quite the solution to my problem.

Does anyone know how to prevent airplane mode from disabling the cellular radio?

Comment: Wouldn't a more sensible solution be to alter the button config so it doesn't enable airplane mode?

Comment: Wouldn't this completely defeat the purpose of having an airplane mode on the phone?

Comment: @spookyjon - Yes, that is exactly the point.  This is what the user is asking for.

Comment: @therefromhere - If that is possible, then sure it is a solution.  I don't have a Samsung Fascinate, so I don't know if the button can or cannot be remapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of PhoneApp.java

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/gingerbread-release/src/com/android/phone/PhoneApp.java

Makes it clear why this will not work.

In contrast to the wifi and bluetooth implementations which register a receiver for `Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED` only when on the list of airplane mode radios, PhoneApp does it all the time:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter =
new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
```

And then unconditionally acts on it:

```
if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED)) {
    boolean enabled = System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
            System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 0;
    phone.setRadioPower(enabled);
}
```

Given the purpose of airplane mode, I'm sure this is an intentional feature and not a bug.

Comment: Thank you for giving a technical explanation of how PhoneApp handles airplane mode.

Comment: You're welcome.  But if you decide to change the Android installation, I would strongly recommend that you do so to prevent the accidental activation of airplane mode, rather than modifying airplane mode to leave the cellular radio on.

Comment: Its not worth the time and effort to go that far.  Looks like lots of people have had issues with airplane mode though: http://androidforums.com/samsung-moment/14206-phone-enters-airplane-mode-random.html

Answer (score 6):

As far as i know you wont be able to do this since the option itself(airplane mode) would be of no use if 3rd party applications are able to access towers with airplane mode enabled on the device.

Comment: I understand your point, but I think that is more of a philosophical reason versus a technical one.  IMHO, Android is meant to be an open platform.  If the user wants to install an application that transparently changes the airplane mode behavior, then they should be able to do so.  In this case, the user doesn't want airplane mode to function since it is causing them to get dropped calls. I am trying to provide a solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes i do agree android is an open source but since we don't have root access in these devices that you buy on market the OS will not allow 3rd party application to do whatever it wants. This has been done for a good reason i.e to avoid security threat. I am not saying it is not doable at all. If at all you want to do this you might have to design your own rom and have root access.

Comment: I understand, and agree that security is important.  I don't see this as an effort to subvert any of the security measures of the platform though.  I see this as allowing the user to customize the behavior of the OS, and if they want airplane mode to behave differently (or not at all), then that is their prerogative.  If this is not technically possible, then that is fine.  But I would like to know why, when according to the documentation, changing System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS should achieve this.

Comment: Thinking about this more, my rebuttal really is that nowhere in the documentation does it say that this cannot or should not be done.  If you could point me to something like that, I would accept it as an answer.  Furthermore, System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS appears to be something which provides the functionality I want.  System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS obviously does not work, which I believe is either a bug or misleading documentation.

Comment: You misunderstand what google means by an open platform.  Unfortunately they do not mean that it is open to end users, they mean that it is open to OEM's who create devices (though if the OEM's want google apps on the device, their freedom to make changes is limited in some respects).

Comment: @chris-stratton Yes, but it is also open for developers too (as stated in http://source.android.com/about/philosophy.html).  Of course, OEMs can impose restrictions if they choose.  However, this digresses from my question.  What I want to know is whether or not I CAN do something, not SHOULD it be done.

Comment: No, it's not well stated and commonly misunderstood, but the ability to alter basic platform functionality is *not* open to (non-device-maker) developers.  Anyone can download the source code and change it, but you can only install changed platform code on a development phone or a rooted consumer phone - or as the device manufacturer, by modifying the image you ship on your devices.  The later is what google means by open.

Comment: @chris-stratton I understand your point, but I think we are overloading the term "open".  When I say it is open to developers, I mean that 3rd party applications are treated as first class citizens.  They can interact with each other, as well as the framework, with the same privileges as any other application.  I firmly believe this type of openness is a core value of Android (I just heard Tim Bray mention it at a talk too). For this question, I am not looking to modify the Android source code or do something that would require rooting. I am looking for a solution within the standard framework

Comment: You are looking to alter the fundamental behavior of the android platform, in particular to make it do something other than what it appears to (airplane mode no longer being an airplane mode).  If for an application to _break_ the platform in that manner didn't require root or useage of some kind of (unfortunately non-existent) mechanism for the user to authorize extremely privileged things, that would be a serious security bug.

Comment: If this is a fundamental feature of the framework, and a security hole, then why does android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS exist in the API?  It is definitely possible to alter this property and effect other radios (like WiFi and Bluetooth).  It appears that the cellular radio does not check this property, which I believe to be a bug.

Comment: It might be because wifi has been permitted and provided on some flights at times?  Wheras AFAIK cellular has never been (though that might change with microcells some day)

Answer (score 0):

If the airplane mode is triggered by a physical button it is possible to override the button press action. Although to achieve this I believe it requires root access to the system.

But to trigger airplane mode from a physical button is a weird idea. IF the button is in the software and while in the call, perhaps you can create a phone application that doesn't have an airplane mode button inside the call screen.

Comment: There was a little more to it than just pressing the button.  I added more details into my original post.  I not think the dialog opened by the side button is application specific, so creating a custom dialer app would not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some applications modify the actual call-in-progress screen, and I know the CityID thing that came pre-installed on my Fascinate (Tells me the city associated with the area code of the number being dialed or incoming) was able to interrupt a call right before it dialed the number to tell me to register the software.  If you can make your own (full-screen) call-in-progress view then it sounds like you have a solution.  Perhaps not the most elegant, but it solves the problem.

I know this is possible to do because Opera-mini can go "full screen" and you can't drag down the task menu from the top; it is not visible to the user while in "full screen" mode.

Comment: On the Fascinate, if you hold down the power/lock button on the side of the phone, it brings up a menu for “Silent Mode”, “Airplane Mode”, and “Power Off” right?  Does this menu not appear when you are in a full screen application?

Comment: tell him to start holding the phone with his left hand?  I think the menu definitely comes up no matter what the app.

Comment: It definitely appears no matter what the application -- but maybe your relative can hold the phone with their left hand instead?

Comment: That still wouldn't answer my original question - how can you prevent airplane mode from disabling the cellular radio?  :)

Comment: I noticed that AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS is part of android.provider.Settings.System  ...is "provider" literally your cell service provider?  Have you tried referring to it by its fully qualified (static) name _android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS_ ?

Comment: "provider" is part of the package name, it has nothing to do with your cell phone provider.  I have imported android.provided, so there is no need to fully qualify the the System class in my code.

Comment: Do you know the details of the Intent fired by that side button?  I assume it would show up in the Eclipse console if you connect to the device via USB.

Comment: The side button is the same thing as the power button on the emulator.  I'm not sure how to link up the physical device with eclipse... link?

Answer (score 0):

I have an app in the market called "Airplane Mode Wi-fi Tool",
it allows the user to do this using the following method:

```
Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), 
        Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS, "cell,bluetooth");
```

Default RADIOS are "cell,bluetooth,wifi" (these are the radios that turn off when enabling airplane mode.

Comment: As I stated in my question,  I already tried using this.  However, removing "cell" from that list (which is what I want) has no effect.  The cellular radio will still get enabled/disabled by airplane mode.

Comment: Actually, my bad, I didn't pay full attention to what you said... Removing wifi or bluetooth works, but cell doesn't and it will never work. When the you tell the system to go into Airplane Mode it will always turn off the cell radio no matter what, it is hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this as it would make airplane mode redundant. One would think that it would be possible to disallow airplane mode from starting somehow. I think the solution you are looking for is a bad idea as it modifies an application to make it useless while still allowing it to run. The problem is a design issue that should be solved by the phone creator. I have no real experience with android (yet) but I would imagine that the kind of functionality you are looking for in the standard framework wont be there.

I'm sure there is a reasonable way around this problem but its unlikely to be in the direction you are going.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I am looking for a technical answer.  I've been discussing the point you made in the comments to the other answers.

Comment: You may not like this answer, but it is a well reasoned explanation of why what you want to do can't be permitted.

Comment: It is not a good answer because it is complete speculation rather than having a technical basis - "I have no real experience with android (yet) but I would imagine..."